# How can I handle address change when update a contract?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

I am using Ganache as local chain for development. I found whenever I update a smart contract in Ganache, it will give a new address for this contract. I am using `new web3.eth.Contract(contractJson, contractAddress)` in frontend to initiate a contract instance. If the contract address changed, the frontend will be broken.

How can I handle the address change in frontend?

Comment: Just store the contract address in a backend configuration file, and retrieve it when the frontend request it.

Answer (score 0):

Without any context to the language you are using or your code, you could initiate an array that will contain your contract addresses. Then when a new contract is created, have that create function push the new address into the end of the array. Then have a new function that returns the last index of this array as a result and that would be your newest contract address which can then be used by the front end.